# Método público onde uma data é passada como parâmetro, um parâmetro apenas

Tags: java, parâmetros

Preciso criar um método público chamado `mostraData` onde uma data é passada como parâmetro (um parâmetro, não o dia, mês e ano separados) e a data é retornada no seguinte formato: **`dd / mm /aaaa`** .

Tenha em mente que, se os valores tem menos dígitos, você deverá preencher com zeros à esquerda para cumprir o formato padrão. Já criei o construtor como me foi pedido no exercício (um por *default* e outro por parâmetro) com os atributos pedidos também. Obrigado.

```
package fechaapp;

public class Fecha {
private int dia;
private int mes;
private int anyo;

public Fecha(){
    this.setDia(1);
    this.setMes(1);
    this.setAnyo(2000);
}

public Fecha(int dia, int mes, int anyo){
    this.setDia(dia);
    this.setMes(mes);
    this.setAnyo(anyo);
}

public int getDia() {
    return dia;
}

public void setDia(int dia) {
    this.dia = dia;
}

public int getMes() {
    return mes;
}

public void setMes(int mes) {
    this.mes = mes;
}

public int getAnyo() {
    return anyo;
}

public void setAnyo(int anyo) {
    this.anyo = anyo;
}
public void mostraData(int fecha){

}
public void calculaSemanaMes(){}
public void calculaSemanaAnyo(){}
public void esAnyoExtraordinario() {}
public void calculaDiaSemana(){}
public void esFestivo(){}
public void esLaborable(){}
public void fechaFormat(){}
}
```

Comment: qual o padrao da data que recebera? ddmmaaaa?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo ddmmaaaa  desculpa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar [**`String#format()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) para incluir os zeros à esquerda.

```
String foo = String.format("%08d", 1234); // 00001234
```

Nesse exemplo, será retornada uma String formatada de tamanho `8` onde, para completar o tamanho que falta (nesse caso, oito) serão serão inseridos 0 à esquerda. Alguns exemplos:

```
String.format("%010d", 123); //0000000123 (incluiu 7 zeros, tamanho 10)
String.format("%05d", 123);  //00123      (incluiu 2 zeros, tamanho 5 )
String.format("%010d", 1);   //0000000001 (incluiu 9 zeros, tamanho 10)
```

Então seu método pode ser assim:

```
public String mostraData(String data) {
    String[] array = data.split("/");

    // Não é uma entrada x/x/x, então retorna a própria data
    if (!(array.length == 3)) return data;

    data = "";
    for (String each : array)
        data += String.format("%02d/", Integer.parseInt(each));
    // remove a última "/" do String#format antes de retornar
    return data.substring(0, data.length() -1);
}
```

Quando chamado:

```
mostraData("10/2");      // Mostra a própria data inserida: 10/2
mostraData("10/2/2015"); // 10/02/2015
mostraData("5/2/2015");  // 05/02/2015
mostraData("10/12/15");  // 10/12/15
```

#### [Exemplo no Ideone](http://ideone.com/dtAo2V)

Answer (score 0):

Assim:

```
int numero = 20102015
char[] digitos = String.valueOf( numero ).toCharArray();

//desta forma, digito[0]+digito[1] = 20, digito[2]+digito[3] = 10, digito[4]+digito[5]+digito[6]+digito[7] = 2015;
//Dae, so vc atribuir na respectiva variavel.
```

Comment: Valeu, mas e se o usuário digitar 2012015 ou 1122015? Como saber qual é o dia e qual é o mês?  Estava pensando se dá para forçar o usuário a digitar / / (1/02/2015 por exemplo) e depois  tiraria a /, o que vc acha? É possível?

Comment: o que voce precisa se ligar é no padrao, se for uma interface, voce pode usar uma mascara, obrigando as barras e o tamanho, ae seria 20/10/2015, neste caso, vc receberia uma String, e seria sempre o padrão. Seria o ideal, voce pode dar um String[] datas = str.split("//"), onde cada datas seria um campo... datas[0]=dia, datas[1]=mes e  datas[2]=ano... Mas para receber sem exception, deve prevenir o formato na entrada.... Este exemplo que passei ta simples de se entender...

Comment: Blz, saquei, obrigado!